# Curl version error while compiling php7.2

Tags: php, php-7.2, litespeed

I'm trying to compile php7.2 with openlitespeed admin panel. I'm stuck with error

```
checking for cURL support... yes
checking for libcurl.pc... using default path
checking for cURL 7.10.5 or greater... configure: error: cURL version 7.10.5 or later is required to compile php with cURL support
**ERROR** Could not configure PHP build
```

I checked curl version `curl -V` its complete output

```
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0gzlib/1.2.11libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 
pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Existing `phpinfo();` page also displaying cURL `7.58.0`

Previously I had compiled php7.1 successfully.

Comment: @RisingSun what to update? 7.58.0 version is already greater than required.

Comment: Have you consider to use LiteSpeed' repository which support PHP 7x on both [rpm](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:rpm) and [apt](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:apt)